# Running good in browsers, but error by flash player directly : ReferenceError: Error #1056

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark

I wrote a flex demo, customized spark TextInput skin with rounded corners and a search icon in it, like mac os x search box, it's running good in browsers (by Flash Player browser plug-in) either .html or .swf, but error by flash player directly.

the error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property allowCodeImport on flash.system.LoaderContext.
    at mx.core::CrossDomainRSLItem/completeCdRslLoad()
    at mx.core::CrossDomainRSLItem/itemCompleteHandler()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

there is the test demo, includes source: http://www.ycoder.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/CustomComponentSkinTest.zip

CustomTextInput

```
package component{
    import skin.CustomTextInputSkin;
    import spark.components.TextInput;
 
    [Style(name="icon", inherit="no", type="Object")]
    [Style(name="radius", inherit="true", type="Number")]
 
    public class CustomTextInput extends TextInput{
        [Embed(source="/images/search.png")]
        private const defaultIcon:Class;    
 
        public function CustomTextInput(){
            super();
            this.setStyle('icon', defaultIcon);
            this.setStyle('radius', 10);
            this.setStyle("skinClass", CustomTextInputSkin);
        }
    }
}
```

CustomTextInputSkin

```
<!-- border -->
 <!--- @private -->
 <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" id="border" radiusX="{hostComponent.getStyle('radius')}" radiusY="{hostComponent.getStyle('radius')}" >
     <s:stroke>
         <!--- @private -->
         <s:SolidColorStroke id="borderStroke" weight="1" />
     </s:stroke>
 </s:Rect>
 
 <!-- fill -->
 <!--- Defines the appearance of the TextInput component's background. -->
 <s:Rect id="background" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" radiusX="{hostComponent.getStyle('radius')}" radiusY="{hostComponent.getStyle('radius')}" >
     <s:fill>
         <!--- @private Defines the background fill color. -->
         <s:SolidColor id="bgFill" color="0xFFFFFF" />
     </s:fill>
 </s:Rect>
 
 <!-- shadow -->
 <!--- @private -->
 <s:Rect left="1" top="1" right="1" height="1" id="shadow" radiusX="{hostComponent.getStyle('radius')}" radiusY="{hostComponent.getStyle('radius')}" >
     <s:fill>
         <s:SolidColor color="0x000000" alpha="0.12" />
     </s:fill>
 </s:Rect>
 <s:HGroup id="textGroup" gap="0" height="100%" paddingLeft="4" paddingRight="4">
     <!-- icon -->
     <s:Image id="icon" includeIn="normal" x="0" y="0" source="{hostComponent.getStyle('icon')}" verticalAlign="middle" height="100%"/>
     <!-- text -->
     <!--- @copy spark.components.supportClasses.SkinnableTextBase#textDisplay -->
     <s:RichEditableText id="textDisplay"
                         verticalAlign="middle"
                         widthInChars="10"
                         left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1"  height="100%"/>
 </s:HGroup>
```

test case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               xmlns:component="component.*"  >
    <s:VGroup paddingLeft="20" paddingTop="20">
        <s:TextInput />
        <component:CustomTextInput  />
        <component:CustomTextInput  radius="12" icon="images/device.png" text="ABC Test ... hohoho" editable="false" />
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Is it possible taht the brwosers you're testing in do not have the debugger player installed?  IF so, you won't see a runtime error.

Comment: I think it is not the problem, It's debugger version too, and it error in standalone flash player either debug or not

Comment: The non-debugger player doesn't show runtime errors; so far as I knew.  The silently fail with no display to the user.

Comment: +1 on question, this is weird indeed

Comment: If the browser version is showing the icon, it probably isn't erroring in the browser as its bombing on the LoaderContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is: **Flex SDK 4.5 support only flash player 10.2+**, and my standalone flash player version is 10.0.*, my flash player plug-in version is 10.2.*. thinks

Answer (score 0):

This line in your skin is the culprit:

```
<s:Image id="icon" includeIn="normal" x="0" y="0" source="{hostComponent.getStyle('icon')}" verticalAlign="middle" height="100%"/>
```

Since you're setting your icon in the style, on creation complete it tries to get that image from the internet which isn't there because HTTP request goes through the browser (however, it should be trying to request the OS browser).  I'm not 100% sure if the error should be there, but my question is, why are you running it in standalone flash player anyway?

Comment: thank you, but i tried to remove this line, the error is still

Comment: hm, could be a bug in the SDK.  My suggestion is to remove code little by little to try to find the problem area, or use debugging to go line by line.

Comment: @sam sha, what was the error?

Comment: the error is ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property allowCodeImport on flash.system.LoaderContext.
    at mx.core::CrossDomainRSLItem/completeCdRslLoad()
    at mx.core::CrossDomainRSLItem/itemCompleteHandler()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

Comment: I am sorry it's my mistake, the reason is: Flex SDK 4.5 support only flash player 10.2+, and my standalone flash player version is 10.0.*, my flash player plug-in version is 10.2.*. thinks everybody

Comment: ahhh.  You should answer yourself and accept it.  It might be useful for other people :)